# NodeJS adding webhook secret

Tags: node.js, webhooks

So there's this website that needs to send data to my nodejs application, and their instruction is this "Use the secret to verify that the events posted to your URL were sent by this website."

But I don't know what attribute to add in the my http header. Is there an option/key/attribute where I can add this secret key to my nodejs app?

Answer (score -1):

if you can, the first solution would be to add that into the header and enforce HTTPS but if the server does not support that and if the server is trusted, You can simply add a `query string` and define the URL like so in that external service:

```
https://mywebhook/update?secret=somesecret
```

and inside your server check if that secret is matching the value `somesecret`

Comment: so the secret key is basically just used for comparison? I don't need to add into the headers?

Comment: No need to add it into the header as it's much easier to add it into the query string

Comment: You should never send a secret in a query string, the URL can be inspected via sniffing web traffic, and is likely logged in log files, etc. Put the secret in a header, and enforce HTTPS.

Comment: this use case is different, it's a webhook that needs to be called by a trusted server

Comment: also I've add your comment thanks for that